# Why set property equal to itself in DOM render - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

consider this block of code from http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

```
function ListItem(props) {
  // Correct! There is no need to specify the key here:
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
    <ListItem key={number.toString()}
              value={number} />
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>
  );
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My question is, where you see:

```
<NumberList numbers={numbers} />
```

I understand this is a component that is being rendered and we are giving it a property that we've created, but what is the significance of setting that property equal to itself? It has me a little confused.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument being passed isn't an instance of `NumberList` (AKA itself), instead it's the array of numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Take a look at the code:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And then we access the `number` properties on this line:

```
const numbers = props.numbers;
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I'm talking specifically about numbers={numbers}

Comment: The property is not being set to itself, a property called "numbers" is being set to `numbers` (the array).

Comment: Could you call the property "numbers" anything you want?

Comment: Wait it just clicked completely for me. That's why we're passing props into the function. Thanks man, up vote for you!

Comment: Great! And yes you can name the property whatever your heart desires! :)